# How to convert table values into plotchar with pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have extracted the label values into table and the table is filled with values. I need to convert them into plotchar. So that, I can use it in a alert.

```
var table t = table.new(position.bottom_right, 1, 12)
var sr_levels = array.new_float(20, 0)
for y = 0 to array.size(sr_labels) - 1
    label_text = label.get_text(array.get(sr_labels,y))
    sr_level_price = str.substring(label_text, 0, 5)    
    table.cell(t, 0, y, sr_level_price, bgcolor = color.yellow)
    array.push(sr_levels,str.tonumber(sr_level_price))

//plotchar(array.get(sr_levels,0),title = "0", char = '')
```

When I uncomment the plotchar line, I am getting the error as "Error on bar 9089, Array size is too large, Maximum is 100000"

[image: Table values]

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I have changed the array insert method. It worked.

```
var table t = table.new(position.bottom_right, 1, 12)
var sr_levels = array.new_float(array.size(sr_labels), 0)
for y = 0 to array.size(sr_labels) - 1
    label_text = label.get_text(array.get(sr_labels,y))
    sr_level_price = str.substring(label_text, 0, 5)    
    table.cell(t, 0, y, sr_level_price, bgcolor = color.yellow)
    array.set(sr_levels,y,str.tonumber(sr_level_price))

plotchar(array.get(sr_levels,1),title = "0", char = '')
```